# I Get ImportError: No module named pathlib, even after installing pathlib with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is my first time asking on this site, so sorry if my question is not layed out correctly

```
y@DESKTOP-MQJ3NCT:~/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning$ python demo_toolbox.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_toolbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pathlib import Path
ImportError: No module named pathlib
```

I have tried:

```
pip3 install pathlib
```

and:

```
sudo -H pip3 install pathlib
```

but continue to get the same error

I am using the windows store version of ubuntu 18 LTS and python 3.7

Comment: When you run `python --version`, what do you get? My guess is that the `python` command belongs to your installation of Python 2, not Python 3. Python 2 does not have `pathlib` built-in. In general, it's better to use `python -m pip install ...` rather than `pip install ...` to make sure the `pip` you're using belongs to the `python` you're actually going to run

Comment: your right, linux defaulted to python 2. sorry for the trivial mistake

Answer (score 8):

When it comes to python, it's quite easy to make the mistake of just running "python ...". When you install python on windows "python" defaults to the python 2.7 installation ( probably changed now that 2.7 is no longer supported) if it is installed.

Ubuntu has the links "python2" and "python3" which makes so much more sense but can still lead to confusion.

If you have a local python Virtual environment, the "python" command defaults to the global install on windows (to further confuse people).

I find it generally best to create my own links to the global python "python27" and "python36" to avoid these confusions.

Same goes for pip. It's best to call

```
python3 -m pip install ...
```

Also. PyCharm is the most amazing Python IDE in the world and it helps with so much.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, turns out it was a simple mistake!

Instead of:

```
python demo_toolbox.py
```

I should have used

```
python3 demo_toolbox.py
```

As Linux defaults to Python 2 or something incompatible with pathlib