# Installing Kite extension for Jupyter-Lab

Tags: jupyter-lab, kite

I have installed the kite app in my os and as well as installed node.js and npm to support kite in the jupyter environment .But when I am using the command pip install jupyter-kite in the Jupter lab terminal environment ,I am getting the following error-

```
~$ pip install jupyter-kite
Collecting jupyter-kite
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/1e/cd99d872ca711efd4b6627d7405435aa73cd1cefff1d2eeb7cacbd3d1dce/jupyter-kite-1.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-aRo7pq/jupyter-kite/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pathlib import Path
    ImportError: No module named pathlib
```

I don't understand the error and unfortunately jupyter kite is still not installed.

Comment: It could be a problem with your installation of pathlib getting confused between python2 and python3 since you've called pip and not pip3. Take a look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788709/i-get-importerror-no-module-named-pathlib-even-after-installing-pathlib-with-p

Answer (score 0):

pip install --ignore-installed pathlib

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it